# Biztalk receive location macros

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I will be receiving excel files in a folder, but I want to only pickup files which starts with a certain naming convention. For e.g. This will be the naming convention of the file BUPA_UNCL_*001_03000088_MED_20221107173306_1*,  the italic part can change and BUPA-UNCL will remain same. So I just want to pickup the files which starts with BUPA_UNCL and has extension of xlsx. How can I achieve this?

Comment: File Filter = BUPA_UNCL*.xlsx ?

Comment: @MarvinSmit You should post that as the answer.   (Note: It is called File mask, rather than Macro).   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/restrictions-when-configuring-the-file-adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file adapter, fill in the path to use and set the file mask to 'BUPA_UNCL*.xlsx'.

Hope it helps,